# Why my Flutter forms can't hold their values?

Tags: flutter, forms, provider, state-management, consumer

I am using the following code to create a simple multi-steps question-answer form, but it seems forms can not hold their values and when I go to the second form and come back, the `textFormField` values are gone.

"Create.dart":

```
class Create with ChangeNotifier {
  String? title;
  String? description;

  int activeIndex = 0;
  int totalIndex = 6;

  changeStep(int index) {
    activeIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

"handler.dart":

```
class FormCreateHandler extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormCreateHandler({super.key});
  static const routeName = '/-form-handler';

  @override
  State<FormCreateHandler> createState() =>
      _FormCreateHandlerState();
}

class _FormCreateHandlerState extends State<FormCreateHandler> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Create>(
      create: (context) => Create(),
      child: Consumer<Create>(
        builder: (context, modal, child) {
          switch (modal.activeIndex) {
            case 0:
              return const FormQuestion1();
            case 1:
              return const FormQuestion2();
            default:
              return const FormQuestion1();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

"form-question1.dart":

```
class FormQuestion1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormQuestion1({super.key});
  static const routeName = '/form-question1';

  @override
  State<FormQuestion1> createState() => _FormQuestion1State();
}

class _FormQuestion1State extends State<FormQuestion1> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Create>(builder: (context, modal, child) {
      return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'title',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty)
                    return 'Please enter the title of question';
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                minLines: 3,
                maxLines: 5,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'description',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 30) {
                    return 'Description must be longer';
                  }
                },
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
                            _formKey.currentState!.save();
                            modal.changeStep(2);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('Back'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: null, 
                        child: Text('Submit'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
                            _formKey.currentState!.save();
                            modal.changeStep(4);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('Next'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

"form-question2.dart"

```
class FormQuestion2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormQuestion2({super.key});
  static const routeName = '/form-question2';

  @override
  State<FormQuestion2> createState() => _FormQuestion2State();
}

class _FormQuestion2State extends State<FormQuestion2> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Create>(builder: (context, modal, child) {
      return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'title',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty)
                    return 'Please enter the title of question';
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                minLines: 3,
                maxLines: 5,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'description',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 30) {
                    return 'Description must be longer';
                  }
                },
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
                            _formKey.currentState!.save();
                            modal.changeStep(2);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('Back'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: null, 
                        child: Text('Submit'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
                            _formKey.currentState!.save();
                            modal.changeStep(4);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('Next'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

How can I modify this code to be able to hold the state of the forms until the user either presses the Submit button or closes the form?

Comment: Use state management solution such as Bloc/Getx.

Comment: @Aks: I use Provide package and thought it's also a state management. But I don't know why it doesn't work?

Comment: How are you managing the state of a TextFormField? using onChanged() or using a textEditingController()?

Comment: @Aks: I am using ` _formKey.currentState!.save();` inside `onPress()` methods of `Next` and `Back`  `ElevatedButtons` as you can see above, but it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: Try the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the other answer by @Aks, I came from a new idea to modify my question forms like below:

"form-question1.dart":

```
class FormQuestion1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormQuestion1({super.key});
  static const routeName = '/form-question1';

  @override
  State<FormQuestion1> createState() => _FormQuestion1State();
}

class _FormQuestion1State extends State<FormQuestion1> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Create>(builder: (context, modal, child) {
      return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'title',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty)
                    return 'Please enter the title of question';
                },

            initialValue:
                Provider.of<Create>(context, listen: false).title,

            onSaved: (value) {
              Provider.of<Create>(context, listen: false).title =
                  value;
            },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                minLines: 3,
                maxLines: 5,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'description',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 30) {
                    return 'Description must be longer';
                  }
                },

            initialValue:
                Provider.of<Create>(context, listen: false).title,

            onSaved: (value) {
              Provider.of<Create>(context, listen: false).title =
                  value;
            },
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
                            _formKey.currentState!.save();
                            modal.changeStep(2);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('Back'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: null, 
                        child: Text('Submit'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
                            _formKey.currentState!.save();
                            modal.changeStep(4);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('Next'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

The modifications are adding following `initialValue` and `onSaved()` properties to each `textFormField`:

```
        initialValue:
            Provider.of<Create>(context, listen: false).title,

        onSaved: (value) {
          Provider.of<Create>(context, listen: false).title =
              value;
        },
```

But as I am not sure if this is the best way of doing that, this question remains open maybe someone would help me to improve the answer furthermore!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with TextEditingController

```
class FromModel extends ChangeNotifier {
String _text = '';

String get text => _text;

void updateText(String newText) {
_text = newText;
notifyListeners();
}
}
```

home_page.dart //with TextEditingController

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
const HomePage({super.key});

@override
State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
final FromModel myFormModel = FromModel();

TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

@override
void initState() {
//helpful to show a pre-filled value
controller.text = myFormModel.text;
super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage()),
            );
          },
          child: const Text("Go to next page"))
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

When you navigate to next page and come back then the _text state will remain same and when you want to clear it then updateTextValue("")

home_page.dart //with onChanged(value)

```
 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const HomePage({super.key});

 @override
State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
final FromModel myFormModel = FromModel();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      //with onChanged()
      ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: myFormModel,
        child: TextFormField(
          onChanged: (newText) {
            myFormModel.updateText(newText);
          },
        ),
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage()),
            );
          },
          child: const Text("Go to next page"))
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: Using this approach should I create a function for each of  `textFormField`s?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: So I think I have got a better idea based on your answer. I will try it and if it worked I will add it as a new answer.

Comment: Could you have a look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75730093/how-to-create-a-list-of-videoplayer-widgets-in-flutter